# How to add 91 to all the values in a column of a pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Consider my data frame as like this

| S.no | Phone Number |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 9955290232 |
| 2 | 8752837492 |
| 3 | 9342832245 |
| 4 | 919485928837 |
| 5 | 917482482938 |
| 6 | 98273642733 |

I want the values in "Phone number" column to prefixed with 91
If the value has 91 already then, proceed to the next value.

My output

| S.no | Phone Number |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 919955290232 |
| 2 | 918752837492 |
| 3 | 919342832245 |
| 4 | 919485928837 |
| 5 | 917482482938 |
| 6 | 919827364273 |

How could this be done?

Comment: the last input has a `33` but output has a single `3`, i assume its a typo

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simplest would be comvert to string, add `91` to the beginning and slice to last 12 digits:

```
df['New Phone Number'] = df['Phone Number'].astype(str).radd("91").str[-12:]
```

Answer (score 6):

#### `Series.str.replace`

```
df['Phone Number'].astype(str).str.replace(r'^(?!91)', '91')
```

---

```
0     919955290232
1     918752837492
2     919342832245
3     919485928837
4     917482482938
5    9198273642733
Name: Phone Number, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 4):

With your shown samples, you could try following code. This makes sure that it catches 10 digits phone numbers only(valid by number of digits).

```
df['Phone Number'].astype(str).replace({r'^(?!91)(\d{10})$' : r'91\1'}, regex=True)
```

[Online demo for above regex](https://regex101.com/r/2lyU9w/1)

Simple explanation would be: changing DataFrame's Phone Number column's value to string and using replace to check if its not starting from 91 and followed by 10 digits then add 91 to it.

Answer (score 2):

You can `apply()` on each element in Series.

```py
def add(x):
    if '91' in str(x):
        return str(x)
    else:
        return '91'+str(x)

df['Phone Number'] = df['Phone Number'].apply(add)
```

Or with lambda in one line

```py
df['Phone Number'] = df['Phone Number'].apply(lambda x: str(x) if '91' in str(x) else '91' + str(x) )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this by boolean masking `astype()` method and `startswith()` method:

```
mask=df['Phone Number'].astype(str).str.startswith('91')
```

Finally use:

```
df.loc[~mask,'Phone Number']='91'+df.loc[~mask,'Phone Number'].astype(str)
```

Now If you print `df` you will get:

```
0     919955290232
1     918752837492
2     919342832245
3     919485928837
4     917482482938
5     9198273642733
Name: Phone Number, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this out....one of way to do it where df is your dataframe name

```
def add_91(x):
    return '91'+str(x)

df['Phone Number'] = df['Phone Number'].apply(lambda x:add_91(x))
```